# Lebesgue measure of a subset [$0,1$]

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-sets

Determine the Lebesgue measure of the subset of [$0,1$] whose elements have neither first nor second digit in their decimal expansion equal to "$0$"

My workings for this problem are as follows:

If $x$ ${\in\mathbb [0,1]}$ has the form $x=0.0...$, then $x$ ${\in\mathbb [\frac{0}{10} ,1)}$$=:$ $A$

If $x$ ${\in\mathbb [0,1]}$ has the form $x=0.x_10...$, then $x$ ${\in\mathbb [\frac{0}{100} ,\frac{1}{10})\ \bigcup 
[\frac{10}{100} ,\frac{2}{10})\ \bigcup ...\ \bigcup [\frac{80}{100} ,\frac{9}{10})\ \bigcup [\frac{90}{100} ,1)\ }$$=:$ $B$

To calculate the Lebesgue measure of $A$ and $B$ I then used the formula $\lambda(A \bigcup B)= \lambda(A) +\lambda(B)-\lambda(A∩B)$

i.e. $1+10(\frac{10}{100})-\frac{10}{100}=\frac{19}{10}=$ $\lambda(A \bigcup B)$

$[0,1]=\lambda(A \bigcup B)\bigcup (A \bigcup B)^c$

So $\lambda(A \bigcup B)^c = 1-\lambda(A \bigcup B) = 1-\frac{19}{10}=\frac{-9}{10}$

This is the method my professor used worked out a similar problem in the notes, however he did not get a negative value for his answer. I'm doubting my solution is correct since it is a negative value for a measure. Any help or push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are right to be alarmed by a supposedly negative Lebesgue measure! The method seems appropriate, but I would look again at your calculation of the measures of $A,B$ respectively. Recall that the Lebesgue measure of the interval $[0,1]$ is $1$, so a subinterval like $A$ should have smaller measure.

Comment: Your claims for both $A$ and $B$ are incorrect.  $A$ should be $\left[\frac{0}{10}, \frac{1}{10}\right)$ and, for instance, the interval $\left[\frac{10}{100}, \frac{2}{10}\right)$ in your definition of $B$ should be $\left[\frac{10}{100}, \frac{11}{100}\right)$ (all the intervals in the union for $B$ have a similar error)

Comment: Thank you for your help @BrianMoehring! Using the changed intervals I got the answer $\frac{81}{100}$, does this seem right to you if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Jack I reached the same conclusion: You exclude the interval $[0,1/10[$ as well as $$[1/10,1/10+1/100[, \dots, [9/10, 9/10+1/100[.$$ So the excluded intervals have measure $1/10+9/100=\frac{19}{100}$ and indeed $1-\frac{19}{100}=\frac{81}{100}$.

Comment: For each pair of digits $x_1$, $x_2$, each set of the form $\{0.x_1x_2\dots\}$ has probability $1/100$.  So it is the same as proportion of 2 digit numbers that don't have their first or second digit as 0.  The chances the first digit are not 0 is $9/10$, and the same with the second digit.  SInce they are chosen independently, the chances both digits are not 0 is $(9/10)^2 = 81/100$.